# How can I create a formula for this sequence?

Tags: calculus

Question in title.

Sequence
1/2
1/12
1/30
1/56
...
Any help is appreciated!
Edit:
So I tried doing this by finding out that the denominator is a quadratic. I need help finding the coefficient and the linear term.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Looks like the denominators are products of pairs of increasing natural numbers. But really, there are _many_ formulas that could have these first four terms.

Comment: So I tried doing this by finding out that the denominator is a quadratic. I need help finding the coefficient and the linear term.

Comment: @Andrew Chin  The sequence goes up by the previous difference plus 8

Comment: The denominator for the $n$th term looks to be $4n^2-2n$.  I'll leave it to you to figure out why.

Comment: @Andrew Chin  I know that that is the correct answer, but how do you get that? Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Think about how you can use the number $1$ to represent $1\times 2$ and at the same time, use the number $2$ to represent $3\times 4$.

Answer (score 0):

There are many such sequences. What have you tried?

**Hint:**

> $ \frac{1}{1 \times 2 } , \frac{1}{3 \times 4 } , \frac{1}{5\times 6} , \ldots $

Can you express an individual term?

Comment: So I tried doing this by finding out that the denominator is a quadratic. I need help finding the coefficient and the linear term

Comment: How would you express each individual term of the denominator as a function of $n$? __Hint:__ What is an expression for the odd numbers?